# setBackgroundDrawable() in android studio is deprecated. is there any other ways to assign bitmap and set as relativeLayout's background?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout, deprecated

Any ideas in assigning relativeLayout's background with bitmap?

```
    RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    bg.setBackgroundDrawable();// deprecated
```

Comment: just use setBackground(Drawable d)

Comment: **... if your minSdkVersion is at least 16.** If you look at source of setBackground it just calls setBackgroundDrawable. So keep using setBackgroundDrawable and don't care ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `setBackground()` instead.

```
RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
bg.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

> ```
>  1) bg.setBackgroudDrawable(Drawable);
>  2) bg.setBackgroundResource(int);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    bg.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

BitmapDrawable() gets deprecated, and i am still having trouble in setting bitmap as my relativeLayout's backgorund

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
bitmap //Your bitmap Image
RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)
bg.setBackground(ob);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but i was wondering how to pass in a declared bitmap image and set relativeLayout's background with my bitmap.

Comment: i did the same method as yours but still returns an error. sobs.

Comment: Error:(63, 34) error: incompatible types: BitmapDrawable cannot be converted to int

Comment: bg.setBackground(ob);

Comment: i have also tried that but it jus crashed and closes my app.